# Button-based chatbots

Tags: chatbot

I have the following use case:

The user starts a chat and selects options (something like a tree), in some cases an administrator can enter the chat and give a response.

My question is: are chatbot systems useful in this case?
I have no experience in chatbot but all the examples that I find on the internet are about NLP.
I appreciate if you can recommend an open source library

Answer (score 1):

I think Dialogflow is a pretty good one to create chatbots. It is free and using custom payloads (tree with options, buttons, chips, etc.). You can make them say some repeated stuff. You would have to type instead.

I have a video where I create a simple chatbot that can take data stored in google sheets and send that details to a user if he asks for the details. If you are interested, please check [it](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3Fur9qlsO-dyxwzUpBhSWtPzbkLyrS7D) out!

Also, here is the Dialogflow console [link](https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/).